# Lack of inter-chapter break in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I'm using tufte-book and include (nine) individual chapters and an Appendix, which I typeset as a (starred) \chapter*{Appendix} (because I don't want it numbered as a chapter).

The below is not a MWE, but gives the core structure of my document:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
.
.
.

\include{PaPCh1}  
.
.
.
\include{PaPCh9} 
\include{PaPApp}
.
.
.
\listoffigures
.
.
.
```

where the Appendix source, PaPApp.tex, starts:

```
\chapter*{Appendix} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} 

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
```

The bulk of the typeset document is fine, with Figures properly numbered 1.1, 1.2, in Chapter 1; 2.1, 2.2, in Chapter 2; etc., and A.1, A.2 etc., in the Appendix.

In the typesetting of \listoffigures there is (properly) a space between the list of figures in each individual chapter, i.e., between Chapter 1 and Chapter 2.  The problem is that the *List of Figures* fails to insert a space between the figures in last ("unstarred") chapter and the figures in the Appendix:

[image: no space between Chapter 9 and Appendix in listoffigures]

How can I ensure there is a space between the list of figures in the last chapter and the list of figures in the Appendix in the listoffigures?

Comment: At the beginning of the appendix, insert this line: `\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}` (or other dimension as desired).

Comment: @barbarebeeton:  Perfect.  Quick and simple.  Post your answer as an *answer* and I'll accept it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm sure there's already another question that's sufficiently similar that it could be considered a duplicate, but I can't find it quickly, so I'll add a somewhat more elaborate answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning of the appendix, insert this line:

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
```

(or other dimension as desired).

Modifications such as added space between entries, page breaks, changes to page length (`\enlargethispage`), can be inserted with the `\addtocontents` command.  The first argument specifies *which* list: `toc`, `lof`, `lot`.  The second argument gives the command(s) to be inserted.

If the insertion is to be applied *before* a chapter, and chapters are `\include`d, the `\addtocontents` *must* be placed in the file with the `\chapter` command, since `\include` will defer such a command until the included file has been fully processed, with the result that the added material will appear later than intended.

Order is always important.  In the present case, `\addtocontents` can be inserted any time before the first figure in the appendix, but it's best to put it near the beginning of the appendix (chapter) so it can be found easily if a change is needed later.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical space is automatically added when you call `\chapter`, as can be seen from its definition in [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls):

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                        \thispagestyle{plain}%
                        \global\@topnum\z@
                        \@afterindentfalse
                        \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
    \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                           \if@mainmatter
                             \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                             \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                             \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                       {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                           \else
                             \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                           \fi
                        \else
                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                        \fi
                        \chaptermark{#1}%
                        \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% <-- Gap in LoF
                        \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% <-- Gap in LoT
                        \if@twocolumn
                          \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                        \else
                          \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                          \@afterheading
                        \fi}
```

So we should insert the following code at the beginning of the appendix

```
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% <-- Gap in LoF
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% <-- Gap in LoT
\makeatother
```

And since `10\p@` is equivalent to `10pt`, the codes could be simplified as follows:

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}% <-- Gap in LoF
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}% <-- Gap in LoT
```

**In this way we could add the same high space as spaces added before beginning list the figures of other chapters in the List of Figures, and it will check atomically whether to add spaces at the top or other places of a page.**